# How to referance closed workbook's range to data validation

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a validation list by VBA code that will refer to another CLOSED workbook range?  I cannot do this `Formula1:="=INDEX('C:\...)"` ?

I can manage with:

```
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sertifika").Range("Ab63:Ab100").Validation

.Delete

.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,

 Operator:=xlBetween, _

 Formula1:=Join(checkref, ",")
```

But for a long string value files.xlsm file will corrupt after saving the file.

Then I tried:

```
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("T").Range("K10:K100").Validation

.Delete

.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, 

Operator:=xlBetween, _

Formula1:="=INDEX('C:\[D.xls]Lists'!$D$2:$D$10,,1)"
```

`Return error 1004`

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft's documentation, you cannot use an external reference with data validation.  You can find the documentation in the following link...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/external-references-data-validation-fails

As a workaround, you can use the ExecuteExcel4Macro method to access the values from a closed workbook.  You can find the documentation in the following link...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.executeexcel4macro

With this method, the values would be accessed to build a string, which would then be used as the source for the validation. ***Note, however, there's a 255 character limit.***

Also, this would mean that you would need to update the data validation each time the workbook is opened to ensure you have up-to-date values.  To do so automatically, the workbook open event procedure can be used.

---

**Workaround Solution**

[Regular Module]

The following macro should be placed in a regular module, and will add the data validation from an external source...

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDataValidation()

    Dim sourcePath As String
    sourcePath = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\" 'change the path accordingly

    Dim sourceFileName As String
    sourceFileName = "Sample.xlsm" 'change the file name accordingly

    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    sourceSheetName = "Sheet1" 'change the sheet name accordingly

    Dim sourceReference As String
    sourceReference = "D2:D10" 'change the reference accordingly

    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim currentValue As String
    Dim validationList As String

    validationList = ""
    For Each currentCell In Worksheets(1).Range(sourceReference) 'any worksheet reference will do for our purposes here
        currentValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & sourcePath & "[" & sourceFileName & "]" & sourceSheetName & "'!" & currentCell.Address(, , xlR1C1))
        validationList = validationList & "," & currentValue
    Next currentCell

    validationList = Mid(validationList, 2)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:A100").Validation 'change the sheet name and range accordingly
        .Delete
        .Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=validationList
    End With

End Sub
```

[ThisWorkbook Module]

The following macro should be placed in the code module for ThisWorkbook, and will automatically update the values for your data validation whenever the workbook is opened...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UpdateDataValidation
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your Answer. But whenever the string items reaches the limit, after the saved *.xlsm open again says " The file corrupt repair .... " Can I assign an array rather than a string ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can.  If at all possible, I would suggest you place the values for your data validation in the same workbook.  If you must refer to an external workbook, I would suggest that each time you open your workbook that you have your code automatically copy the up-to-date values from the external workbook to a hidden worksheet in your workbook.  Then you can simply refer to those cells as your source.

Comment: Yes, I did it what you suggested and It is ok. Again thank you for your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without macros using the Excel data model. First put the dropdown options in a source workbook, and name that range (using formulas --> Name manager). Close this workbook. In the main workbook, go to Data --> Get Data --> From file --> From Excel workbook. Then choose the source workbook (needs to be closed) and click import. Select the named range from the list. The click Load. Then click on the loaded data in the main workbook, click Data --> Queries and Connections --> Properties and click on the query properties icon next to the name of the query (a rectangle with two squares on it). Set the data to refresh when opening the file, and to refresh every 5 minutes. You can then use this copy of the data in the main workbook as a source for a data validation list.